# Determine number of random changes applied to set, given the probably of a single bit being changed

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, random-generation

We have values $X_i$ for $i \in  \mathbb N^+, i \leq M$. Initially $\forall i X_i  = 0$

Proccess $P$ takes a random $I = Uniform(1,M), I \in \mathbb N$ and increments $X_I$, i.e. adds $1$ to its value.

E.g. if in a particular run of $P$ $I$ happens to be $4$, and $X_4$ had been $12$ before this run, then now it becomes $13$

Repeat process $P$, $N$ times.

After the $N$ repetitions, let $p_i = \mathbb P(X_i > 0)$

Note that since $I$ was random and uniform, $p_i = p_j, \forall i,j \in (1,M)$
Let $p$ denote this constant value of $p_i$.

Determine $N$ as a function of $M$ and $p$.

Comment: Could you provide the exact text of the puzzle, and cite its source?

Comment: @Kodiologist Unless you feel my initial question is unclear, I don't see why that would be necessary - my question doesn't actually need the origianl problem. I'd like an answer to my question - not the solution to the puzzle.

Comment: If you DO think the q is unclear, then please do say so! What was unclear about it?

Comment: If you're trying to solve the puzzle, you probably have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If you really are interested in the question for its own sake, I don't know what "the probability of any particular value having been changed at any point" could mean, given that you already said that the value to be changed at each step was chosen at random uniformly. That is, it seems that $p$ must be $1/M$.

Comment: To Repeat: " I'd like an answer to my question - not the solution to the puzzle." I'm well aware of what and XY-problem is and this is not it.

Comment: `p` would equal `1/M` if we only changed a value once. But we're doing that step repeatedly, so there are loads of opportunities to change the value. But also lots of opportunities for the value to be changed more than once.

Comment: I've rewritten the problem in a Mathematical terminology - hopefully this is clearer? @Kodiologist

Comment: Your three formulations are all ambiguous and appear to be three distinct questions.  In the first, the meaning of "any particular value" is unclear.  In the second it's not apparent what the superscripts "old", "new", and "newest" actually mean.  In the third it's unlikely the "noise" is remotely like the increments described in the second.

Comment: Re #2 Damn, I wasn't sure that the superscripts were helping - changed. (For reference...) you take $X_i$, which started at 0, and you increment it. So if $X_3$ had been 5, then now it is 6. And then you're looking at the set of $X$s at the end.

Comment: Re #1, I agree that "any particular value" isn't 100% clear. Hopefully you can see what it means, in the context of #2? If you have any alternative phrases to recommend I'm happy to change.

Comment: Re #3, as I said, "the noise is applied by the above process". The noise selects a random pixels and then sets it's value randomly, thus completely destroying the data. The point is that I don't *care* what the result of the noise is on each pixel - I only care whether it has been hit or not. Hitting it repeatedly is irrelevant. This is why in #2 $p_i = P(X_i > 0)$, rather than being, for exampe, $E(X_i)$ ... we don't care how many times it's been incremented - only whether or not it has *ever* been incremented.

Comment: @whuber Any better now? I guarantee you that the different formulations ARE the same, modulo my ability to express myself :)

Comment: I think I understand this new version. One question: where you write $i < M$, do you mean $i ≤ M$?

Comment: @Kodiologist Probably. Where?

Comment: @Brondahl The first sentence after "is a more mathematical terminology".

Comment: got it. Yes - I think I flipped between $(0, M-1)$ and $(1,M)$ whilst initially writing it :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks - I think I'd convinced myself it was hard than that :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $i$, $P(X_i > 0)$ is just the probability that $i$ was picked at least once during the increment process. This is the complement of the probability that $i$ was never picked, which is $\left(\tfrac{M - 1}{M}\right)^N$. So $p = 1 - \left(\tfrac{M - 1}{M}\right)^N$. Solving for $N$ yields $$ N = \log_{(M-1)/M} (1-p) .$$